# Java JMX Message None UTF Body to String

Tags: java, messaging, jmx

I am subscribed to AMQ. I am trying to receive and store specific messages as they come across the wire. Some of the message that I am receiving have garbage values in body and when I perform the `toString()` after casting to a `TextMessage` the text is `null`. The error that I received is a UTF exception. I fully expect the message to fail the `.getText()`. Is there a way in `Message` to get the text without having to validate the xml or validate the that it is UTF?

Thanks

Comment: This probably means that the messages are binary or in an non-utf encoding - can you get the byte stream and process that?

Comment: They are in UTF format but some of the encoding is not UTF. These message are bad but, still trying to capture them.

Comment: `They are in UTF format but some of the encoding is not UTF` - that is a contradiction in terms. Thus, it's not in UTF. You have two options - try ISO-8859-1, which will mangle most characters above ASCII; or try to write an encoding-sensitive scanner yourself. Try to go with option #1.

Comment: My response was to declare that the messages are marked UTF but, some of the characters being sent are not correct.